# тупенькая meaning

Tags: значения, морфология, суффиксы

What does `тупенькая` means in below sentence?

```
-Ты говоришь по-английски?

-Нет, я тупенькая )
```

Comment: It's a colloquial and diminutive for "dumb".

Comment: Diminutive for "stupid", not offensive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means *thick (headed)*. Grammatically it is the word ***тупая*** with the suffix ***-еньк***(ая) (-ая is ending)

***-еньк*** (-оньк) is a suffix of adjectives, adverbs and nouns which imparts them diminutive connotation to either downtone their rudeness (as in ***тупенькая*** vs ***тупая***), make them sound gentle or, in case of adverbs, to reduce their intensity and absoluteness

> малый/ая - мал**еньк**ий/ая
>   чёрный/ая - чёрн**еньк**ий/ая
>   скоро - скор**еньк**о
>   тихо - тих**оньк**о
>   дочка - доч**еньк**а
>   папа - пап**еньк**а (archaic)
>   мама - мам**еньк**а (archaic)
>   Петя - Пет**еньк**а
>   Катя - Кат**еньк**а
>   деревня - дерев**еньк**а